# File Id of a file on a given path (box windows sdk)

Tags: box-api

How can i get a file id of the file from its path (e.g. https://dav.box.com/dav/abc.dox) using box windows SDK. Actually I have developed a VSTO add-in that open files directly from box.com through webdav server and I want to fetch file information from box.com when the file is opened in Microsoft Word. Can this be accomplished?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not think Box has direct support for this capability.

The only way I can think of accomplishing this would be to traverse each level of the directory tree matching the path names

Comment: how can i get the path of a file using box windows sdk?

Comment: Referencing files via path in general is a bad idea, as these references are broken as soon as the file is moved. However, the API does allow you to construct the path via the path_collection returned from the file information endpoint: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get  You will need to add the optional path_collection field param to your request

Comment: okay i did exactly like that.. just a random question it is, other than path matching in which other way we can track which file is currently opened in Word?

Comment: Each file has a unique identifier property, `ID`, and a version property, `etag`. You can use these to identity which (and which version) of a file is currently open.

Comment: Dropbox seems to think that referencing files via path is not that bad of an idea.